# Regular expression for "$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.xml"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What should my regular expression look like if I want to validate that `$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.xml` always starts with `$` and always ends with `xml`

```
"$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.xml"
Pass

"$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.xm"
Fail

"$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.py"
Fail

"A/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.xml"
Fail
```

Edit... So... The right regular expression is...

```
"^\$.*xml$"
```

The the method after the implementation of the regex checker looks like...

```
public bool ValidateConfigPath(string config)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(config, @"^\$.*xml$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return match.Success;
    }
```

And all my unit tests pass...

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ValidateConfigPath_InCorrect1()
    {
        var t = new TfsWrapper();
        var isValid = t.ValidateConfigPath("$/Quantz/Main/CSS Calculator/main.py");
        Assert.IsFalse(isValid);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidateConfigPath_InCorrect2()
    {
        var t = new TfsWrapper();
        var isValid = t.ValidateConfigPath("C:/Quantz/Main/CSS Calculator/main.xml");
        Assert.IsFalse(isValid);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidateConfigPath_Correct()
    {
        var t = new TfsWrapper();
        var isValid = t.ValidateConfigPath("$/Quantz/Main/CSS Calculator/main.xml");
        Assert.IsTrue(isValid);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need a regular expression for this? Do you have the option of just checking that the first character is a '$' and the last four are ".xml"? That would be a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's not a strict requirement for using regular expressions, I recommend the more straight-forward approach of simply checking the starting and ending characters:

```
string.startswith("$") and string.endswith("xml")
```

With the above, the intent is absolutely clear to anyone, including people who don't understand regular expressions.

Comment: Smart! That's a nice one too.

Answer (score 2):

[Have you read a tutorial?](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

```
^\$.*xml$
```

`^` is the beginning of the string. `\$` is a literal `$` character. `.*` is 0 or more arbitrary characters (in fact, no line breaks, but that does not seem to matter in your input example). `xml` is really just `xml`. And `$` is the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
  ^\$.*xml$
```

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13255/Validation-with-Regular-Expressions-Made-Simple) for details